# Is it recommended to use =default destructor with empty constructor?

Tags: c++

I have constructor `A(){}` 
Situation: There is only assignment and not memory allocation for member variable inside constructor.
In this situation, Is it recommended to use `~A()=default`? or Should I go for `~A(){}`?

Comment: Even better (if you don't need to declare it `virtual`) would be to not declare the destructor at all. See the Rule Of Zero.

Comment: @nathanoliver I don't agree with the dupes. This core issue with the question is not about the `=default`, but about the need for a destructor. Which isn't needed. The dupe should be regarding the Rule of Zero, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724)

Comment: @JHBonarius You're right that no destructor is preferred, but my interpretation of the question is that it is specifically asking about the difference between the two.